# about opengles and texture on android

Tags: java, android, textures, opengl-es-2.0

As we know,in the **OpenGL ES**  the class `Renderer` on android has 3 `function:onDrawFrame, onSurfaceChanged, onSurfaceCreated.`
and we can load the texture in the **onSurfaceCreated** and **onDrawFrame**.
I want to know can i load the texture before the **"Renderer"**.Likely, I have a class named "Map",and can i load the images texture in the **"Map"** before the "GLSurfaceView" created. or can i load the images texture before the function **"onSurfaceCreated"** and **"onDrawFrame"**.

if someone know it,please help me.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Not easily. But (almost) anything is possible.

The critical concept to understand here is that OpenGL calls operate on a **current context**. Before you can make any OpenGL calls, you need to create a context, and make it current. The context being current applies to a thread, so different threads can have different current contexts. I don't think it's clearly defined what happens if you attempt to make OpenGL calls without having a current context, but it certainly isn't anything useful. The most likely outcomes would be nothing at all, or a crash.

`GLSurfaceView` handles all of the complexity of setting up contexts for you. It creates a rendering thread that runs independently from the main (UI) thread, creates a context, and makes that context current in the rendering thread. Once methods on your `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` implementation are invoked, you already have a current context, and you're ready to make OpenGL calls.

Now, if you want to make OpenGL calls before all of that `GLSurfaceView` magic happens, you have to do a lot of this yourself. You can call methods of the [EGL14](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGL14.html) class to create your own context, and make it current. It's slightly painful, but not terribly difficult. I don't have full code handy, but you should be able to either find examples, or figure it out from documentation. You will use methods like `eglChooseConfig()`, `eglCreateContext()`, `eglMakeCurrent()`, and probably a handful more on the way.

Once you're done with that, you can make your OpenGL calls for creating textures, etc. But unfortunately, that's not the whole story yet.

Once your `GLSurfaceView` comes to life, it will create its own context as usual. Different OpenGL contexts can share resources (like textures), but they don't do that by default. Since `GLSurfaceView` knows nothing about the context you already created, it won't share resources with your context.

To enable resource sharing, you have to interfere in the creation of the context by `GLSurfaceView`. You can do this with the `setEGLContextFactory` method. This allows you to hook up your own context creation for the `GLSurfaceView`, where you can now create a context that shares resources with the context you created earlier, and used for your texture loading.