# Drawing shape on button click using OpenGL in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

As new to the android OpenGL section.I had downloaded the sample example given on site [Displaying Graphics with OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html)

so run the downloaded sample and its running with an error and display the output as expected.
I had do draw the triangle in the GLSurfaceview and its working fine.
The screenshot for the triangle drawn:-
[image]

Now as the requirement change i have to draw the triangle onclick of the imageview but not on starting the application.
Here is the screenshot for the above mention requirement

[image]

the black triangle is the imageview and right side is the GLSurfaceView area where i need to draw the triangle.Currently when i click the imageview its doesn't draw image but gives some exception, here is the logcat message:

```
by Log Tag libEGL

by Log Message called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

i not able to understand where i m doing something wrong.Stuck of this part.

So, this kind of requirement can be completed with OpenGL in Android.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to make OpenGL calls from your UI thread. `GLSurfaceView` creates a rendering thread, and an OpenGL context that is current to this rendering thread. All the rendering initiated by the `GLSurfaceView` is then executed in this rendering thread.

You can't make OpenGL calls without having a current context, and the UI thread does not have one unless you specifically create one. Doing that can get hairy, and I wouldn't recommend it for this case. If you're interested to read up on it anyway, I answered a related question the other day where I try to explain how to create and use multiple contexts: [about opengles and texture on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953805/about-opengles-and-texture-on-android).

The cleanest way to do what you need is to store a representation of what needs to be drawn (e.g. the coordinates of the 3 triangle vertices in your case) as member variables in the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` implementation. The flow is then:

1. In response to the UI input, you invoke methods on the `Renderer` implementation that set the triangle coordinates in member variables of the class. You may want to use `synchronized` methods because these coordinates will be accessed both by the UI thread and the rendering thread.
2. You trigger a redraw of the `GLSurfaceView` by calling its `requestRender()` method.
3. The `onDrawFrame()` method of the `Renderer` implementation will be invoked in response. It grabs the new coordinates from the member variables, and draws the triangle.