# Opengl-es 2.0 and multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Recently I've come up with an idea to load all the data, textures and shaders in a separate thread in android. There's unfortunately really little information about multithreading connected with android and Opengl-es 2.0. I've already done some research and here's what I've learnt (please notify me if there's sth wrong):

By calling `setRenderer(glRenderer);` android starts a new thread for OpenGL and I can invoke OpenGL functions only in scope of this renderer's context which is attached to the new thread.

This is my GLRenderer class (implementing Renderer):

```
public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {
    //...
    Context mContext;
    boolean stopRendering;
    //...

    public GLRenderer(Context c, String stagePath)
    {
        mContext = c;      
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        if(!stopRendering)
        {
            //render
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        new LoadingThread().execute(this);

        // Set the clear color to black
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    }
```

And here's the class which is supposed to load all the data in a separate thread:

```
class LoadingThread extends AsyncTask<GLRenderer, Void, Void>
{
    GLRenderer glRenderer;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(GLRenderer... args) 
    {
        glRenderer = args[0];

        glRenderer.stopRendering = true;

        glRenderer.SetupShaders(); // shaders don't compile, compile status returned is 0

        glRenderer.stopRendering = false;
        return null;
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
     * the result from doInBackground() */
    @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
   {

   }


};
```

Is there any way to successfuly and securely invoke GL functions from other thread started from the renderer's thread? I'm starting a new thread in the OnSurfaceCreated function but shaders just won't compile there...
Should I actually do OpenGL stuff in a separate thread or it's not really recommended in android? Becouse GL renderer is a new thread, it doesn't block the main UI thread, right? So no matter the loading time it will never "hang up"?

Comment: Here's an earlier answer I wrote about using OpenGL from multiple threads in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953805/about-opengles-and-texture-on-android/24967032#24967032.

Comment: Thanks, your answer there resolved many of my doubts and made me sure that in my case, such an overhead isn't worth. Glad to know it's possible though